# How to load payment tokens in a Smartwatch

Tags: nfc, payment, wear-os, hce

First I would like to know if it is possible. 
If it is, how could I load a dynamic token for a close loop payment in a Smartwatch. I am familiar with the HCE on Android phones but the way it should work on a Smartwatch in really new to me.
Thank you so much

Comment: do smart watches have nfc support?

Comment: Yes, the Samsung Gear that we will use has NFC support